# react native streaming stop with react navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, iframe, react-navigation, jsx

I am making an application that has two streams (A AND B) which can be accessed from the home screen.

well, the problem is the following:

when I enter any of the two streams (A) everything works fine, but when I access the other stream (B) from the Drawer navigation, said stream pauses every time I press play

I am passing them through an iframe with react native webView

my navigation method is in React navigation Drawer

I have tried several ways to solve this, changing to Stack, using jumTo, etc, but with none I have been successful

I am new to react native, please help me with this problem

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE!!!!

I found that my videos in the iframe are stopping because the screens are not closing, I tried this by creating a copy of my app and using Stack with the "Replace" component, but now I see that drawer has no replace component.

How could I do this using Drawer navigation?